# error in system.data.dll file in visual studio 2012 connecting database using c#

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm developing simple database project in visual studio 2012, i tried to connect to mysql database. It showed this error in system.data.dll file 
error statement :

> The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in
>   assembly 'System,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type
>   'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' could not be
>   resolved  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll

can any one help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

what Database connection driver are you using? Since you are using MySQL database you should use MySQL Connectors for .NET and reference Mysql.Data dll http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/